# Load columns dynamically with HTML 5

Tags: html, dynamic

Hay stacker I was wondering if it is possible to have columns dynamically load with HTML 5 like http://www.hitpost.com/ when scrolling left and right?

Any help you can give me would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make AJAX requests in the `scroll` event.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, sorry I forgot its still in private beta, how it works is when you scroll left or right the content is dynamically created loaded into columns. Im working on developing a pure HTML5 site so would like to do it all with HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to detect the scrolling, and perform a certain action accordingly. Look into jQuery's [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) like SLaks mentioned, which is probably the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: You cannot use AJAX without Javascript.  Javascript is part and parcel of HTML5 (eg, HTML5 local storage or web workers); don't be afraid to use it.